# why are my 2d game objects passing through each other?

Tags: unity, physics, rigidbody

So I've been looking around for a while and can't seem to find an answer for this. I am trying to make a game where you stack shapes as high as possible. I have an OnMouseDrag script so I can grab a shape and put it on top of another. but for some reason when I'm dragging a shape, the shapes will just pass right through each other and glitch and start spinning excessively and also passes through other colliders such as the box colliders 2d on both sides of the screen. If anyone could help me I would very much appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you're moving your game objects via their `Transform` component. [This is a common error when you want physics-based collisions, because moving with the `Transform` completely bypasses the physics engine](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/154463/39518). If you want the physics engine to have a say in where the objects go, you need to talk to it via your `Rigidbody` / `Rigidbody2D` component, applying forces/velocities rather than direct position teleporting.

Comment: Oh ok. So how would I go about fixing this?

Comment: See the linked answer, under the heading "So, solutions:" If you need help implementing that advice, please consider editing your question to include more details about what you've tried and where you're stuck.